# i create two function for dispaly place and blog in my project(web site) but only one function displaying

Tags: python, django

## views.py

```
def fun(request):
    obj=place.objects.all( )
    return render(request,"index.html",{'results':obj})

def func(request):
    obj=blog.objects.all( )
    return render(request,"index.html",{'blogresults':obj})
```

## urls.py:

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.fun, name='fun'),

```
path('', views.func, name='func')
```

]

Comment: In urls.py, both urls have the same path, so it will always find the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same view function and you try to put both on one page, so you do not need two functions, in this case if you want to show the place and the blog on one page, you can try this:

## view.py

```
def fun(request):
    obj_0 = place.objects.all( )
    obj_1 = blog.objects.all( )

    return render(request,"index.html",{'results':obj_0, 'blogresults': obj_1})
```

## url.py

```
urlpatterns = [ path('', views.fun, name='fun')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change second url path to:

```
path('func/', views.func, name='func')
```

And you can hit second path via `<your_domain>/func/`

I would suggest giving meaningful names to your views like:

```
def place(request):
     ...

def blog(request):
     ...
```

Comment: sir i changed to " path('func/', views.func, name='func') " but it did not work...?

Comment: How are you calling both the views ? What is the error ?